# R dplyr select() isn't working and there's no error code

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a table from the dslabs gapminder dataset showing only the life expectancies and fertility rates of African countries in 2012. The first part of my code works, but after select() it just stops working and I don't even get an error code. I'm sure it's probably something super trivial but I'm still new at this. Will someone please help me figure out why this code isn't working?

```
library(dplyr)
library(dslabs)
data(gapminder)
df <- gapminder %>% filter(., continent == "Africa" & year == as.factor(2012)) %>% select(., 'fertility' <= 3 & life_expectancy >= 70)
```

Comment: I think your `select` statement is not correct. Isn't that a `filter` statement

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but it's always worth using ``dplyr::filter()`` rather than ``filter``, since ``filter`` can often collide with ``stats::filter``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, all of the logical expressions should go inside the `filter`.  If the functions are getting masked by other the same function from another package, either do this on a fresh `R` session with only `dplyr` loaded or use the `::` to specify the package source that holds the function (as showed in the comments)

```
library(dplyr)
gapminder %>% 
    dplyr::filter(continent == "Africa",
           year == 2012, 
           fertility <=3,
           life_expectancy >= 70)
```

-output

```
#country year infant_mortality life_expectancy fertility population gdp continent          region
#1    Algeria 2012             22.4            76.2      2.82   37439427  NA    Africa Northern Africa
#2 Cape Verde 2012             22.4            71.9      2.33     500870  NA    Africa  Western Africa
#3      Egypt 2012             22.6            70.5      2.81   85660902  NA    Africa Northern Africa
#4      Libya 2012             12.9            75.5      2.41    6283403  NA    Africa Northern Africa
#5  Mauritius 2012             12.8            74.1      1.50    1258335  NA    Africa  Eastern Africa
#6    Morocco 2012             26.4            74.1      2.71   32984190  NA    Africa Northern Africa
#7 Seychelles 2012             12.2            73.7      2.21      94524  NA    Africa  Eastern Africa
#8    Tunisia 2012             13.6            77.4      2.02   10881450  NA    Africa Northern Africa
```

---

`select` is used to select the columns and not the `rows` -  `filter` or `slice` does that

Comment: @ReeNadeau that is interesting.  Can you show your `packageVersion('dplyr')` and also can you run this on a fresh R session

Comment: I restarted the R session and it worked :) Thank you!